# inkscape - copy shape of an object without the content

Tags: inkscape

I've imported a .png image and then cropped it with an rectangle. Now I'm looking for a method to copy the outline shape of the resulted element.

I need just the contour, without the image content. The cropped image is rotated, so simply making a new rectangle isn't a solution right now.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share an image to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. It's not very clear at the moment.

Comment: So this way:  I want a shadow below my 'image-cropped' element, so I'm duplicating it, and I wish it to be fill with solid color, but there's is a copied photo, and how to fill it, so just a color remain?  
There could be also no solution I guess,  for now I just make a second rectangle before rotating the perspective (and squeezing).

Comment: What I am looking about is similar to "Paste Size", but this one is missing the rotate coordinates. So it would be something like "Paste Size and Transformation" or "Paste Shape".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one imports a photo to Inkscape, he can get a drop shadow by selecting Filters > Shadows and Glows > Drop shadow. If the photo is scaled or rotated, it still works.

Surprisingly, if the photo was cropped by adding a vector element as a clip path (Object > Clip > Set), the drop shadow filter does not work, because the clipping happens also to the shadow.

Fortunately the clipping can be released (Object > Clip > Release). After that one can duplicate (=ctrl+D) the vector element. Now there are two vector elements. One of them can be used again as the clipping path of the photo. Another can be colored (=grey fill, no stroke) and be used as the drop shadow  (Object > Lower to bottom + move a little).

If a blurred shadow is needed, it's easiest to go Filter > Shadows ang Glows > Drop Shadow.

**Addendum:**  The story above concentrates to making shadows due the comments. Of course the extracted clipping path is available for other purposes, too